# Accessibility and Access

Tags: accessibility, ms-access-2010

I'd like to add some accessibility features to my Access forms, for users that have difficulty with the standard 11pt-font, white-background, black-text set-up.

Windows itself has a bunch of Display Settings options for altering window font sizes, background colours etc, but these don't cover Access forms altogether well - they'll change the colour of items where system colours are used, but font face or size of labels, input boxes, data grids etc can't be changed this way as they're not connected to those settings. The Datasheet settings under File -> Options seem to have no effect on datasheet forms (or subforms).

I can't find any accessibility options in Access, not so much as a Zoom function (1998 called, it wants its GUI back, etc etc). It seems ridiculously excessive to have to fire up the VBA editor and do something like:

```
Public Sub AccessbilityBtn_Click()
    Me.Detail.BackColor = RGB(whatever)

    Me.HeadingLbl.FontSize = 18
    Me.HeadingLbl.Width = 'whatever accomodates bigger text
    Me.HeadingLbl.Height = 'whatever accomodates bigger text
    Me.FieldLabel1.FontSize = 14
    Me.FieldLabel1.Width = 'whatever accomodates bigger text
    Me.FieldInput1.Width = 'whatever accomodates bigger text

    '... to infinity and beyond ...
End Sub
```

Or to craft `FormName_BigText` versions of every single form and replicate the entire behaivour of my entire system.

So, does Access have accessibility options? If so, where are they? And can they be called from VBA? If not, how can accessibility options be implemented into Access forms?

Comment: A good question would be : in that case, should you care about accessibility ? It's a bit like the "should I put a ge-bigger-text fucntionality in my site or should I let the user use whatever accessibility tools he wishes (browser, 3rd party, magnifier,...) ?" question. In my opinion, on the web you should just care about semantic and helping the tools, and in your case I would just let the users with view problems handle it as they usually do with everything written in not-so-small font.

Comment: Yes I should - I need to add accessibility features because it's come up as a genuine problem. And Access does not seem to ship with the nice things that browsers ship with. In my browser I can hit Ctrl-+ and suddenly everything is bigger. I might have some js scripts to change colour schemes or contrast. Access does not (as far as I've been able to tell) have these features, and it also seems rather unaccomodating to adhere to Windows' display settings in any regards other than system colours.